# Write a Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

In lead object Feilds called Industry,So seleted Industry Feild On Banking Then get error How to do this through Validation Rule

Comment: Can you elaborate in detail as in what is your requirement ? Also, what have you tried and what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: we  Do not accept lead from banking I try this rule----------------AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Industry_c,'Banking'),
    
)

Comment: Unless you clarify your exact requirement, community won't be able to help you out. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/275478/edit) your question to include all the relevant details and the issue you are facing.

Comment: You need to complete the Salesforce Trailhead tutorials [such as this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules)

Answer (score 1):

"Industry" is a built-in field for the Lead object, so you don't need the "__c" in the field name in your validation rule (and note when you *do* need it, there are two underscores). The "__c" is used to indicate custom (not built-in) additions your organization has made to Salesforce. So in your case, a validation rule of simply **ISPICKVAL(Industry, "Banking")** should work to block use of that industry.

If you are going to do that, you can also consider simply de-activating the "Banking" picklist option in Setup > Object Manager > Lead > Fields & Relationships > Industry. That way it is never presented as a choice.